# How do I make a Picture Story type of game in Ruby/C++?

Tags: c++, c, ruby, programming-languages

I just want to ask on how could I create a Ruby/C++ coded game that is somewhat like this:

-More of a Interactive picture oriented game. On the game, The player can click certain parts of an image to interact to it.

Ex: In a picture of a Mall, The player can click the elevator to go to the top part of the mall or He could also interact with the people (static picture of people) and talk to them.

I'm making an interactive type of game for our class computer exhibit and I would really be glad if someone out there would be willing to help me out with the tutorials and resources that I need.

I can code basic Ruby and C++, so some libraries, gems or tutorials would surely help me out with this.

Thanks!

Update:
I've found a flash game that is similar to what I'm trying to make: http://bit.ly/jROuEF 
(It's a big game though around 9mb, so I guess it would load slow)

Answer (score 2):

If it's simply click and follow (and a few animations etc.) you *could* structure it as a website. That would probably be simpler than writing an app for it.

Comment: hmmm...Thank you for that answer, But I guess making a website for that type of interactive game would not be suited. Since I also need some dynamic interactivity for the game. Like as the game story continues, the player cannot go back to a certain place or something like that.

Comment: You could do that using Javascript.

Comment: Flash is kind of dated. Silverlight is not cross platform. I would recommend HTML plus javascript.

Comment: +1 I actually think HTML+Javascript could work quite well for a point and click adventure type game.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim Moonlight as part of the Mono project would give me a cross-platform solution. http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight :)

Comment: Yes but it's not as feature rich as silverlight or as cross platform (mobile devices, multiple browsers etc.) as HTML5+Javascript.

Comment: Well, I appreciate it...But really, I need something to make it a program and not a website. It's part of learning for me too.